# How to Create a Heat map with two factors and one numeric data type in R?..

Tags: r

Consider the following scenario :-

```
       Col1 Col2 Col3
```

Col1 & Col2 are belongs to character data type.
Col3 is the numeric data type.

Each value in Col3 denotes the combinational behavior of Col1 & Col2.

So, I want to create a data matrix of size (Col1 * Col2) and stores the col3 value accordingly.

I would be really happy, If someone could help me on this.....

Comment: do you have character variables or factor variables ? do you need a heatmap or a matrix ? your question does not correspond that much to the title...

Comment: Finally I need a heat map. But without converting your input data set in to data matrix, we can't create heat map.

Comment: Currently I have two factor variables and one numeric variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions from `data.table` package

```
data <- data.table(a = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'), b = c('d', 'e', 'f', 'e'), c = c(3,5,6,7))
casted <- dcast(data, a~b, value.var = 'c')
```

If you need matrix as a result, you have to do additional conversion:

```
matr <- as.matrix(casted[, 2:ncol(casted), with = F])
rownames(matr) <- casted[[1]]
```